# Cant able to run sqlplus in windows batch script || ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am using below batch script and want to execute a SQL query and save the data in CSV file

```
call sqlplus myuser/mypass@abcdb@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xyz-scan.abc.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=abcdb)))" @C:\myfolder\myquery.sql
```

but it is giving me "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception" error when i run my batch script
[image]

I also tried with simple TNS (note: my tns location is "D:\app\iis_admin\product\11.1.0\client_1\network\admin\sample")

```
 call sqlplus myuser/mypass@abcdb @C:\myfolder\myquery.sql
```

But again getting same error.

my myquery.sql contain below query

```
set feed off
set pagesize 0
spool C:\myfolder\myresult.csv
prompt sysdate
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;
spool off
set head on
set feed 6
quit
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume it might be about too large gap between versions you use.

- screenshot suggests it is Oracle **8.0.6** (gosh, that's old! Dates in 1997)
- text mentions **product\11.1.0**

Therefore, I'd upgrade the former so that it would be able to *speak* with the latter.

Comment: _"what action should i take ???"_    Install a new oracle client.  But also be aware that even your mentioned database (11.1) is also so old as to be out of support.